# Connection marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08000), ErrorCode(0)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a spring boot application using hikari and a Mysql database.
There is my hikari configuration :

```
HikariPool-1 - configuration:
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................none
connectionInitSql...............none
connectionTestQuery.............none
connectionTimeout...............300000
dataSource......................none
dataSourceClassName.............none
dataSourceJNDI..................none
dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
driverClassName................."org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
exceptionOverrideClassName......none
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............none
idleTimeout.....................600000
initializationFailTimeout.......1
isolateInternalQueries..........false
jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://mydatabase?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................27000000
maximumPoolSize.................70
metricRegistry..................none
metricsTrackerFactory...........none
minimumIdle.....................20
password........................<masked>
poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
readOnly........................false
registerMbeans..................false
scheduledExecutor...............none
schema..........................none
threadFactory...................internal
transactionIsolation............default
username........................"user_name"
validationTimeout...............10000
```

There is my database configuration :

```
wait_timeout    28800
interactive_timeout 28800
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    180
connect_timeout 10
```

I keep getting this error and I don't understand why :

```
2022-10-20 14:39:37,465 WARN c8c20a5b-7877-4830-bac8-ece994ae84e5 c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection: HikariPool-1 - Connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@5737d116 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08000), ErrorCode(0)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: (conn=10076858) Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente (Read failed)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:153)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:274)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:363)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.execute(MariaDbStatement.java:501)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.commit(MariaDbConnection.java:721)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:387)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
```

The connection **5737d116** referenced in the stacktrace has been created just 2 hours before :

```
2022-10-20 12:37:30,333 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@5737d116
```

And here is the state of the pool of connection just before the exception occured :

```
2022-10-20 14:39:00,600 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:00,601 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:00,601 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2022-10-20 14:39:02,197 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - Before cleanup stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:02,197 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - After cleanup  stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:02,197 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2022-10-20 14:39:30,601 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Before cleanup stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:30,601 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - After cleanup  stats (total=21, active=1, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:30,601 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
2022-10-20 14:39:32,198 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - Before cleanup stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)
2022-10-20 14:39:32,198 DEBUG   c.z.h.p.HikariPool: HikariPool-2 - After cleanup  stats (total=20, active=0, idle=20, waiting=0)
```

Thanks in advance for your help